# AS3 Think time simulation

Tags: actionscript-3, time

In my cards game, I'm trying to simulate the opponent to think about his choice. During this time I want to let appear on the screen a thinking cloud... this is possible with the command TCloud.visible = true; and false to let it disappear. After the think time (5 seconds) I want some more seconds ( like 2-3 seconds) so you can see what the opponent has decided, and then start again... I've already written the logic part of the actions, just need you to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Timer class and do something like this:

```
// create a timer that dispatch an event after 3 seconds

private function wait3seconds():void {
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
    timer.start();
}

private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I got error 1119 on
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, nextTurn);
referring to the property COMPLETE ... what's wrong?

Comment: Fixed using TIMER_COMPLETE instead of COMPLETE... THank you!